# What is the general format of Ruby "diff-lcs" diff output?

Tags: ruby, diff, lcs

The [Ruby `diff-lcs` library](https://github.com/halostatue/diff-lcs) does a great job of generating the changeset you need to get from one sequence to another but the format of the output is somewhat confusing to me.  I would expect a list of changes but instead the output is always a list containing one or two lists of changes.  What is the meaning/intent of having multiple lists of changes?

Consider the following simple example:

```ruby
> Diff::LCS.diff('abc', 'a-c')
# => [[#<Diff::LCS::Change:0x01 @action="-", @position=1, @element="b">,
#      #<Diff::LCS::Change:0x02 @action="+", @position=1, @element="-">],
#     [#<Diff::LCS::Change:0x03 @action="-", @position=3, @element="">]]
```

Ignoring the fact that [the last change is blank](https://github.com/halostatue/diff-lcs/issues/2), why are there two lists of changes instead of just one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have better luck with a better example. If you do this:

```
Diff::LCS.diff('ab cd', 'a- c_')
```

Then the output looks like this (with the noise removed):

```
[
  [
    <@action="-", @position=1, @element="b">,
    <@action="+", @position=1, @element="-">
  ], [
    <@action="-", @position=4, @element="d">,
    <@action="+", @position=4, @element="_">
  ]
]
```

If we look at `Diff::LCS.diff('ab cd ef', 'a- c_ e+')`, then we'd get three inner arrays instead of two.

What possible reason could there be for this? There are three operations in a diff:

1. Add a string.
2. Remove string.
3. Change a string.

A change is really just a combination of removes and adds so we're left with just *remove* and *add* as the fundamental operations; these line up with the `@action` values quite nicely. However, when humans look at diffs, we want to see a *change* as a distinct operation, we want to see that `b` has become `-`, the "remove `b`, add `-`" version is an implementation detail.

If all we had was this:

```
[
  <@action="-", @position=1, @element="b">,
  <@action="+", @position=1, @element="-">,
  <@action="-", @position=4, @element="d">,
  <@action="+", @position=4, @element="_">
]
```

then you'd have to figure out which `+/-` pairs were really changes and which were separate additions and removals.

So the inner arrays map the two fundamental operations (*add*, *remove*) to the three operations (*add*, *remove*, *change*) that humans want to see.

You might want to examine the structure of the outputs from these as well:

- `Diff::LCS.diff('ab cd', 'a- x c_')`
- `Diff::LCS.diff('ab', 'abx')`
- `Diff::LCS.diff('ab', 'xbx')`

I think an explicit *change* `@action` for `Diff::LCS::Change` would be better but at least the inner arrays let you group the individual additions and removals into higher level *edits*.

Comment: Ah yes, that looks right - each inner array represents a "change" (a "delete/add" pair at the same position).  So `Diff::LCS.diff('a1 b2 c3 d4', 'aw bx cy dz').size # => 4` since there are four changes.  Thanks!

Comment: @maerics: Yeah, if there was just one flat list of edits you'd have to manually match up the `@position` values to extract the C-level edits from the ASM-level list of `Diff::LCS::Change`s. The [documentation for the Perl version](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-Diff/lib/Algorithm/Diff.pm#diff) is worth a look: "The description is a list of *hunks*; each hunk represents a contiguous section of items which should be added, deleted, or replaced. The return value of `diff` is a list of hunks..."

Comment: I understand the structure of the array of arrays, but I'm still left wondering how I would get a human-friendly difference. Such as `old content` wrapped in a `del` tag and `new sentence` wrapped in an `add` tag.

Comment: @Archonic: Maybe a new question is in order, that would give everyone more room to work with than comments. Basically, you backtrack from the `@action`s inside the hunks to reconstruct the before and after versions.

Comment: Figured it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648875/make-output-of-diff-lcs-human-readable/15648876#15648876